# AngularJS : common service provider values is not getting in different controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-services, angularjs-factory

I have created an application in angularjs with ng-view feature, the application is working fine, but one issue is that i am having a commonService which is been shared between view controllers, I am setting the values in commonService from one controller but not able to get the initialzed values in another controller. I have replicated the issue within a plunker

In the plunker click the **Set Details** hyperlink which will initialize values within the commonService and then click **View Details** hyperlink which will open the view in another browser tab, but commonService values is showing empty. each view controller is been defined in separate module

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1fObbao97b1pBW31T20Y?p=preview)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Agent Portal</title>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="AgentApp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="firstTemplateController">
      <div class="masthead">
        <h3 class="text-muted">Project name</h3> 
        <ul class="nav nav-justified">
            <li ><a href="#/firstTemplate">First Template</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#/thirdTemplate">Set Details</a></li>
            <li ><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="openInNewTab()">View Details</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div ng-view></div> 
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you forget to call this.setDetails method. this.getDetails is returns job object, that will be empty till this.setDetails  method not called.

Comment: @Ved yes i have called that, check in `thirdTemplateController`, i have called `commonService.setDetails($scope.personDetails, $scope.addresDetails);`

Comment: Ya.. got it.. sorry I didn't find that..

Comment: You are not getting value because,  $scope.message = "values from commonService->"+JSON.stringify(commonService.getDetails()); will call getDetails method only. And getDetails method has empty obkect.

Comment: but I have initialized the commonService in  thirdTemplateController  right,,,if you put a console for getDetails in thirdTemplateController, there it is printing the details........,so getDetails  method should also return those initialized values in secondTemplateController right

Comment: Yes, you have initialized  common service in thirdTemplateController.But when you call from service in secondTemplateController , It will no return value initialized by thirdTemplateController. It runs the separate copy of service.

Comment: so what will i do to achieve that...........

Comment: Just a min. I will see it..

Comment: @Ved okay.....i have explored many things....even there are options for sending the values as params in ng-view, in my case i am having a big json values (not like as shown in plunker), so i cant send it as params, since it will be displayed within the browser URL, so that is why i  thought of the using service for storing and retrieving which will be a clean way

Comment: If you want to pass data between controllers, than go for $broadcast or as you created service, it is best way.

Comment: cant we achieve using services or factories

Comment: I am thinking about that But service or factory is initiated only once.

Comment: okay.....but we use that for communication between controllers right, also initialization is okay....we can change values in services right

Comment: No. If controller A changes any value in service, than it for controller A  only. controller B will run the Initial copy of service.

Comment: I have created a plunker. check it. It may help you:.http://plnkr.co/edit/qeGOhDfllYLQA7UHYemo?p=preview